# Filtering Realm object returns nil when there is a 100% value

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am stucked in situation when I am trying to .filter Realm objects with predicate and it returns nil, but I do the same query in Realm studio and it DOES work there.

I can return idFolder, but can't query the object using it

```
folders = realm.objects(Folder.self)
currentFolder = String(describing: folders?.first?.idFolder)
```

My code of querying:

```
if let idFolder = currentFolder {
        let folderName = folders?.filter("idFolder = '\(String(describing: idFolder))'").first?.name
        let name = callAlert(title: "Add new well for folder \(String(describing: folderName))")
    }
```

The problem is that **folderName** = **nil**

I double checked the value of **currentFolder** and it is equal to what I have in my Realm database. Here is a screenshot:
[Realm database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hgKJ.png)

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
I also tried to use new querying instead of chaining request, didn't work.

Comment: Try: `"filter(idFolder == %@", idFolder)`

Comment: @Scriptable your answer is also helpful, thanks. the problem was with String(describing: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is on the query
`"idFolder = '\(String(describing: idFolder))'"`
the correct one should be like that
update
`"idFolder == \(idFolder)"`

Comment: It turned out that String(describing: ) was a problem, thank you! Also had to get rid of it in currentFolder